# atof() removes one character at the end

Tags: c, token

I am aware of the low quality of the code, I am a beginner to programming in C.
The following program attemps to receive input from the user, turn it into tokens and then perform basic math with them. If the input exceeds 8 characters: ('256 + 256'), it fails to properly return a correct result, instead `256 + 256` is interpreted as `256 + 25.
It's been hours and hours of debugging and I cannot pinpoint the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1024

typedef struct tokenReturn {
    int arrayMembers;
    char* tokens[];
}
t_return;

t_return *getAndTokenize(char* delim) {
    // Get user input and store it as a string literal.
    char* input = malloc(1024);
    char lit_in[MAX];
    
    if (fgets(input, MAX, stdin) == NULL) {
        perror("Error: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strncpy(lit_in, input, MAX);
    free(input);
    // Create the return structure to return not only the char* array but the max index as well.
    t_return *return_struc = malloc(sizeof(t_return) + MAX);
    if (return_struc == NULL) {
        puts("Allocation error");
        perror("Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Assign first member due to the weird behaviour the strtok function has.
    char *token = strtok(lit_in, delim);
    return_struc->tokens[0] = token;
    
    int i = 1; // We have to start at one since we already have one token stored in the array
    while (true) 
    {
        // Check to see if all the tokens have been obtained.
        if((token = strtok(NULL, delim)) == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        return_struc->tokens[i] = token;
        i++;
    }
    // Assign i to arrayMembers so that we can determine array length.
    return_struc->arrayMembers = i;
    
    return return_struc;
}

float sum(float x, float y) {
    return x + y;
}

float multiply(float x, float y) {
    return x * y;
}

float subs(float x, float y) {
    return x - y;
}

float division(float x, float y) {
    return x / y;
}

int main(void) {
    // Init
    printf("Operation: ");
    t_return* tokens = getAndTokenize(" ");
    float a = atof(tokens->tokens[0]);
    char symbol = tokens->tokens[1][0];
    float b = atof(tokens->tokens[2]);
    float result;

    // Check for the operation being done
    switch (symbol) {
        case '+':
            result = sum( a, b );
            break;
        
        case '-':
            result = subs(a, b);
            break;
        
        case '/':
            result = division( a, b ); 
            break;
        
        case '*':
            result = multiply( a, b );
            break;
        
        default:
            puts("Operation not recognized!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Result is: %.3lf\n", result);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: If you are using gcc, learn to use gdb - it will serve you beyond this program.  If using VS Code, learn to use breakpoints and step in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAndTokenize` copies the input into `lit_in`, which is an automatic object inside `getAndTokenize`. Once `getAndTokenize` returns, the memory for `lit_in` is no longer reserved, and the pointers you put into the `t_return` structure pointing into `lit_in` are no longer valid. Some of the other code in `main` does things that reuse that memory for other purposes. Change `getAndTokenize` to keep the input in an allocated buffer that is not freed until the program is done using the data in it.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense, thank you!!!

Comment: YUP, adding `static` in front of the variable fixed it. Thank you so darn much! Have a nice day!